# Reading structure from Binary file to Linked List leading to an infinite loop

Tags: c++

This is how my structure is constructed

```
struct dNascimento{

    int day, month, year;

};

struct morada{

    string street;
    int doorNum;
    string postCode;

};

typedef struct student{

    unsigned int id; //Número mecanográfico
    string name;
    string password;
    morada addressStudent;
    string course;
    dNascimento birth;
    int money;

    student* next;

}* studentPointer;
```

I'm adding student records to the linked list through this function

```
void addStudent(studentPointer studentToAdd) {

    studentToAdd->next = NULL;

    if (head != NULL) {

        current = head;

        while (current->next != NULL)
            current = current->next;

        current->next = studentToAdd;


    }
    else
        head = studentToAdd;

}
```

This is the function I use to save the students in the linked list to the binary file

```
void saveStudentsToFile() {

    FILE *file = fopen("records.bin", "wb");

    if (file != NULL) {

        if (head != NULL) {

            current = head;
            int numberOfStudents = 0;

            while (current != NULL){

                if (fwrite(current, sizeof(student), 1, file) != 1)
                    cout << "\n\t> Erro ao guardar o aluno " << current->name << " no ficheiro!\n" << endl;

                current = current->next;
                numberOfStudents++;

            };

            cout << "\n\t> " << numberOfStudents << " aluno(s) guardados com sucesso!\n" << endl;
            //^ Number of students saved successfully
            fclose(file);

        }else
            cout << "\n\t> Não há registos de alunos para guardar!\n" << endl;
            //^ There are no students to save to the file
    }else
        cout << "\n\t> Erro ao abrir o ficheiro para guardar registo de alunos!\n" << endl;
        //^ Error opening file to save students
}
```

This is the method I'm using to load the students saved from the file to the linked list

```
void loadFile() {

    FILE *file = fopen("records.bin", "rb");

    if (file != NULL) {

        studentPointer studentReader = new student;
        studentReader = (studentPointer) malloc(sizeof(student));
        int numberOfStudentsLoaded = 0;

        while (!(fread(studentReader, sizeof(student), 1, file) != 1)){
                addStudent(studentReader);
                numberOfStudentsLoaded++;
        };

        fclose(file);

        cout << "\n\t> " << numberOfStudentsLoaded << " aluno(s) carregado(s) com sucesso!\n" << endl;
        //^ Number of students loaded successfully
    }
    else
        cout << "\n\t> Erro ao abrir o ficheiro dos registos!\n" << endl;
        //^ Error opening file to load records
}
```

This is the method I'm using to list the students in the linked list

```
void listStudents() {

    if (head != NULL) {

        current = head;
        while (current != NULL) {
            cout << "\n\t> ID #" << current->id << endl;
            cout << "\t> " << current->name << endl;
            cout << "\t> " << current->password << endl;
            current = current->next;
        };

    }
    else
        cout << "\n\t> Não tem registos guardados!\n" << endl;
        //^ No records saved to display
}
```

When I add records manually to the linked list and use `listStudents()` to display them, they show up perfectly, but when I save the student records to the binary file and load them, the `listStudents()` method goes on an infinite loop to only display the last record saved in the binary file.

Keep in mind that every variable in the structure is correctly initialized before saved.

> How students show up through `listStudents()` when I insert them manually
>   http://image.prntscr.com/image/73459c40d81d462ca043ee414d1556d0.png
>
> How students show up after I `saveStudentsToFile()` and `loadFile()`
>   http://image.prntscr.com/image/c3dfb61235de46b7adb757d0762883a9.png

Comment: What does "add records manually" mean?

Comment: I recommend using `unsigned int` for the date members.  I still haven't seen a negative day, month or year value and the `int` type means that negative values are allowed.

Comment: @Scott Hunter, Instead of loading from the file, to add manually through input from the console.

Comment: I see no code that reads from the console to add records.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with your code is that you cannot use `fread` to read `student` data from file (the same applies to `fwrite`). Your student class is not POD (Plain Old Data), it contains `string` variables which cannot be initialized by reading from binary file with fread. You should use `fstream` to write field by field to output file, and then read field by field. Or convert your student struct to POD, ie: replace all `string name;` with `char name[64];`.

Also, if you store: `student* next;` then you should not use its value, address will not be valid.

Your code looks more like C than C++, for example here:

Why do you:

```
    studentPointer studentReader = new student;
    studentReader = (studentPointer) malloc(sizeof(student));
```

you dont need `(studentPointer) malloc(sizeof(student));`. Whats more you should not use `malloc` as it will not call constructors for `string` variables.

In the end never ending loop is probably caused by Undefined Behaviours in your code.

[edit]

The reason for infinite loop is because you dont allocate each time you read a student from file, so you end up with all the same students. Below is corrected code.:

```
    int numberOfStudentsLoaded = 0;
    while (true){
            studentReader = (studentPointer) malloc(sizeof(student));

            if ((fread(studentReader, sizeof(student), 1, file) != 1)
               break;

            addStudent(studentReader);
            numberOfStudentsLoaded++;
    };
```

Comment: I've changed my `string` variables to `char variableName[64]` to still be able to use `fwrite` and `fread`.

But I'm still getting the loop. If I only have a student saved in the file, it displays it correctly, but when it's more than that, it goes into a loop to display the last student saved in the file.

I don't think that having `student* next` saved in the binary file is relevant, because it gets set to `NULL` when I use `addStudent(studentPointer studentToAdd)` method.

Comment: Thank you so much it fixed the problem and I am still able to read strings through that method. There's no need to swap `string` variables to array of `char` !

Comment: If string is std::string then for short texts - like 14 chars it uses  Short String Optimization feature, and then it indeed will look like it works. So try with longer strings to see how it will fail.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I changed my `string` variables. Thank you very much for your help. Best regards!